# App Crash on Orientation Change (just when I set 2 different backgrounds for portrait and landscape modes)

Tags: android, drawable, out-of-memory, android-orientation, orientation-changes

I use a JPG background for root view of my activity, and I put it in `drawable` folder. Anything was fine until I decided to use 2 different wallpaper for portrait and landscape orientation. So, I put second wallpaper in `drawable-land` folder.

Now the problem is: when I test the app on real device, everytime I change orientation twice (from portrait to landscape and then from landscape to portrait), the app crashes and I see a loooooong error log, regarding `OutOfMemoryException`:

```
09-08 14:13:21.567: E/dalvikvm-heap(16536): Out of memory on a 16384016-byte allocation.
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ad2478 self=0x149a9d0
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   | sysTid=16536 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074488712
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=346 stm=52 core=1
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:530)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:505)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:357)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:777)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2844)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2781)
09-08 14:13:21.567: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:412)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:179)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at com.test.IndexActivity.onCreate(IndexActivity.java:58)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3371)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
09-08 14:13:21.577: I/dalvikvm(16536):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 14:13:21.577: D/AndroidRuntime(16536): Shutting down VM
09-08 14:13:21.577: W/dalvikvm(16536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ad1210)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.IndexActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3371)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at com.rahpou.android.parnian.IndexActivity.onCreate(IndexActivity.java:58)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    ... 12 more
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    ... 24 more
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:530)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:505)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:357)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:777)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2844)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2781)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:412)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:179)
09-08 14:13:21.597: E/AndroidRuntime(16536):    ... 27 more
```

It seems that loading another drawable costs too much, but I have seen many apps using large and variuos graphics and wallpapers and had no problem. So, how I can prevent this memory leak and help android recycle/destroy previous background drawable to avoid OutOfMemory?!

*if it is important, my phone screen and the wallpapers has HD (720p) resolution, and both wallpapers (port and land) are about 100 KB in size.*

**EDIT:** I tried the first answer and modified it in my code because I have a `ScrollView` as root view and the wallpapers are set to its background drawable.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);            

    ScrollView root = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.root);
    // this line causes NullPointerException:
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) root.getBackground();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
    bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

but things got worst and I got `NullPointerException` on first orientation change on the line specified in code.

Another thing is that why 16 MB memory is required to allocate for creating a HD bitmap?!! I think 1280px x 800px x 8(bytes/pixel) = 8 MB so why there is 16 MB needed?!! (I refer to first line of LogCat where it says "Out of memory on a 16384016-byte allocation." and 16384016-byte ~ 16 MB.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);            

    myImage = findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) myImage.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
        bitmap.recycle();
    }       
}
```

and in manifest:

```
<activity
  ...
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
  ...
>
</activity>
```

Comment: I don't load the bitmap by code, I just set it in xml as activity layout background and android itself manages its loading. So, how and when I can tell android to recycle previous background when orientation changes?!

Comment: @yrajabi how "another drawable" is loaded in your application?

Comment: @yrajabi Do you mean that you have two layouts? one for portrait and one for landscape?

Comment: yes, I have 2 layout for each orientation, and 2 background for each one, in "drawable" and "drawable-land" folders. And you know, Android itself chooses the proper background when rotating screen.

Comment: thanks, but I got another error, please take a look at my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this in your `mainfest.xml`

if your android:targetSdkVersion="12" or less

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

if your  android:targetSdkVersion="13" or more

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screensize">
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where is this feature (conditionals in AndroidManifest.xml) documented? It doesn't seem to be mentioned on the Developers page.

Comment: This answer is not a solution to the problem, it merely avoids the problem by preventing android from handling these configuration changes and leaves it up to you the developer to deal with them. To do properly though is more work that properly saving state. Generally it is not advised unless you have a specific use case for it. See more here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekN2zvFytZk

Answer (score 0):

The answers with `configChanges` seem to mitigate the issue for the moment, but if we take a look at LogCat we see that he has an `OutOfMemoryException`.

This is the result of loading a large bitmap, when there's no memory enough to allocate.

I suggest you take a look over Android's documentation on how to fix: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: thanks, I read it but it's about how to load and use bitmaps by myself. But here, I have problem with something that android handles itself, I just defined background in XML, but when screen rotates, it runs outOfMemory! and requres 16 MB just for creating the background! I'm wondering how this is possible when I don't handle anything!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have already solved this problem, but here is the solution that I have found thanks to your answers.

I have use two different ID for the layout, and the following OnConfigurationChanged function:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    BitmapDrawable drawable = null;
    if (findViewById(R.id.root_land) != null) {
        drawable = (BitmapDrawable) findViewById(R.id.root_land).getBackground();
    }
    if (findViewById(R.id.root_port) != null) {
        drawable = (BitmapDrawable) findViewById(R.id.root_port).getBackground();   

    }
    if (drawable != null){
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

And in the Manifest (into the Activity) I put this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screensize">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `System.gc()` in `public void onConfigurationChanged` method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    System.gc();
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```